# Prediction of unlikely events with multiple time series (R)

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

So here's the problem:

I am dealing with about 200 time-series of banking accounts that have drawn on a credit at some point. I know the point when they got the credit (let's call this point t(credit) ) and know the account balance from t(0) - t(credit)

Now I want to build a model which tells me, how high the chance for taking a credit is for other accounts that have not taken one so far.

In other words: I want to know at which point a customer takes on a credit.

I know that this is not realy a multiple time series, since the series don't effect each other.

The closest slution so far is described in this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271539746_Time-series_event-based_prediction_An_unsupervised_learning_framework_based_on_genetic_programming) which is not totaly reproducable to me in some parts.

My questions:

What kind of statistical test/ machine learning algorithm can solve the problem?
Is there an R-Package that might help me?

https://csvshare.com/view/4ydm2-Lyr

Here's the data for the first 5 IDs, each one is a single time-series. The third column gives information about wether the income is due to a credit. Some IDs might have taken on more then one credit, but to keep it simple, I'm only interested in the last one.

Comment: This is not really a programming problem and would be better asked on crossValidated, as it relates mostly to statistical methodology. That said, you should look into time series mining. There are a number of nice literature review papers on the topic.

Comment: I believe a survival/hazard model would fit your data well. I'm far from being an expert in that topic, but, there is probably someone around that can help you.